# How to place the elements in relative layout

Tags: android

I have a design in relative layout which has a central element. I want another element to the left of that central element and the base of both of these should be at same level. I have tried alignBaseline but of no use.

Please help ... !!!

Comment: Can you post your xml code as well ?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ff0" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/first"
        android:layout_width="50dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/second"
        android:layout_width="50dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/first"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/first"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/first" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the atributes of the RelativeLayout, check [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html) for instructions and some examples.

But to sum it up you need:

`android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/center_element"`

`android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/center_element"`